# Nuxt application on Apache Server

Tags: apache, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

Good time of the day!

I'm using statically generated website with `npm run generate` command, and while all the pages which are placed inside pages directory work just fine (dynamic pages, all implemented functionality, etc), pages which do not exist are simply return the default web server error page.

On local machine with `npm run dev` i'm able to be forced to the **'Page not found'** error generated by Nuxt, while on the production server running Apache, I can't use middlewares provided by the packages (for example *@nuxt/sitemap*) as well as any page which may trigger error (40*,5**,3**) is handled directly by the web server.

Since `npm run dev` just starts the **express** web server, i guess any routing rules put in place by the express could be reproduced in the Apache **.htaccess** config, i just don't know where to look for them.

Here is my configuration from the Vue project **without** Nuxt, where everything works as intended (redirects, etc)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>

# Fonts
# Add correct content-type for fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot 
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/font-woff .woff
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
```

However, while running the same file on Nuxt application, every request just redirected back to the home page.

This is how the router configured in the **nuxt.config.js**

```
router: {
    mode: 'history',
    middleware: [
      'i18n',
      'check-auth'
    ]
}
```

So from my point of view, i've provided web server with information it needs to properly identify when the page does not exists (inside the application), but instead of trying to do so, it simply checks whether the file exists physically.